# Error al usar TimerTask para desactivar un BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

Lo que intento hacer que al pasar X tiempo se desactive un `BroadcastReceiver`. Esto ya lo logre, y funciona. Lo probé usando un Switch y funciono, cuando estaba en `on`.Se activaba y cuando estaba en `off` no. Inicialmente lo tengo desactivado, mi objetivo es que cuando pase un tiempo X se active. También comprobé que entrara al método `run()` usando el `Log.d()` y entro. El problema esta cuando llamo al método, también intente copiar el método `activarFuncion()` para la clase Temporizador, pero me dice que `cannotresolve getPackageManager()`, en fin QUE NO FUNCIONA.La clase `Call_Reciver` es la que hereda de `BroadcastReceiver`. Alguna idea???

Aqui esta la clase COMPLETA (solo le faltan los import):

```
public class Activity_llamadas extends Activity {
Button boton;
EditText editText;
TextView textView;
TextView textView2;
TextView textView3;
Switch aSwitch;
int h=0,m=0;
Vibrator vivatror;
long[] pattern = {0, 500, 100, 1000};

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ComponentName reciver= new ComponentName(this,Call_Reciver.class);
    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(reciver,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_llamadas);
    aSwitch= (Switch)findViewById(R.id.switchAcvivar);


    SimpleDateFormat date=  new SimpleDateFormat("mm"); 
    String mhora= date.format(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
    textView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textHoraAct);
    textView3.setText(mhora);
    vivatror = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewHora);
    textView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewhora2);
     boton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonHora);
     boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             TactivarBroucast();
        }
     });
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.getHora);
    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mostrarHora(textView);
        }
    });
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.getHora2);
    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mostrarHora(textView2);

        }
    });

 }
   public void setTxHora(int h,int m, TextView t){
   t.setText(String.valueOf(h)+": "+String.valueOf(m));
}

private void mostrarHora(final TextView t) {
    final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,int minute) {
                 int h= view.getCurrentHour();
                 int  m = view.getCurrentMinute();
                   setTxHora(h,m,t);
                }
            }, h, m, false);
    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Selecciona la hora");
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
   public void stardNotificacion(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder= (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("SiyOp");
    mBuilder.setContentText("La aplicion ha comensado a funcionar a las "+getSystemHora());
    NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,mBuilder.build());

}
public void iniciarBrocast(){
int i=20;
Intent intent= new Intent(this,Call_Reciver.class);
 intent.putExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE ,TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE ); 
PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),15635435,intent,0);  

AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+(i*1000),pendingIntent);
}

public  void activarFuncion(){
    ComponentName reciver= new ComponentName(this,Call_Reciver.class);
    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(reciver,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
 public void getSwitchState(View v){
    if(aSwitch.isChecked()){
        activarFuncion();
    }
    else {
        ComponentName reciver= new ComponentName(this,Call_Reciver.class);
        PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(reciver,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
public void TactivarBroucast(){
    Date date= new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,5000);
    date=c.getTime();
    Timer time= new Timer();
    time.schedule(new Temporisador(),date);
}    
}
```

**Método en la clase**

```
MainActivity:

    public void activarFuncion(){
        ComponentName reciver= new ComponentName(this,Call_Reciver.class);
        PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(reciver,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

**Clase Temporizador:**

```
   public class Temporizador extends TimerTask {
    Activity_llamadas activity_llamadas;
    @Override
     public void run(){
      activity_llamadas.activarFuncion();//<----------ESTA ES LA LINEA 15
      }
}
```

Y este es **Logcat:**

> ```
> 02-26 18:57:55.005 26935-26975/com.example.andry.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
>                                                                              Process: com.example.andry.myapplication, PID: 26935
>                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                  at
> ```
>
> com.example.andry.myapplication.Temporisador.run(Temporisador.java:15)
>                                                                                        at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)

**NUEVO LOGCAT:**

> 02-26 21:05:22.020 27421-27605/com.example.andry.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
>                                                                                    Process: com.example.andry.myapplication, PID: 27421
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare()
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:208)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:122)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.(Activity.java:765)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.example.andry.myapplication.Activity_llamadas.(Activity_llamadas.java:28)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.example.andry.myapplication.Temporisador.run(Temporisador.java:15)
>                                                                                        at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)

Comment: Agrega a clase Activity_llamadas por favor.

Comment: Esa excepción del "nuevo logcat" te indica que tienes que llamar a Looper. Mira este enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597742/what-is-the-purpose-of-looper-and-how-to-use-it

Comment: Ya agrege la clase @ Jorgesys♦....espero tu ayuda...GRACIAS